# Android Dev - How to address audio output channels

Tags: android, audio, xamarin.android

Does anybody have experience how to address specific audio output channels of an USB connected audio interface (with multiple outputs) for an android app? The `AudioManager` `GetDevices()` function does not work for this purpose.

Comment: I am confused about the audio output channels. Normally, we use the UsbManager to access the state of the USB. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary

Comment: Thanks, will take a deeper look into this. I hoped the audio classes are capable for it.